# How to restrict time difference to same day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
     'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
     'time_1' :['2173-04-03 12:35:00','2173-04-03 12:50:00','2173-04-03 
           12:59:00','2173-04-03 13:14:00','2173-04-03 13:37:00','2173-04-04 
           11:30:00','2173-04-05 16:00:00','2173-04-05 22:00:00','2173-04-06 
           04:00:00','2173-04-06 04:30:00','2173-04-06 08:00:00']
       })
```

I would like to create another column called `tdiff` to calculate the time difference

This is what I tried

```
df1['time_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time_1'])
df['time_2'] = df['time_1'].shift(-1)
df['tdiff'] = (df['time_2'] - df['time_1']).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

But this produces an output like as shown below. As you can see, it subtracts from the next date. Instead I would like to restrict the time difference only to the same day. Ex: if `Jan 15th 20:00:00 PM` is the last record for that day, then I expect the `tdiff` to be `4:00:00` (`24:00:00: - 20:00:00`)

I understand it is happening because I am shifting the values of time to subtract and it's obvious that the highlighted rows are picking records from next date. But is there a way to avoid this but calculate the time difference between records in a same day?

[image]

I expect my output to be like this. Here NaN should be replaced by the current date (`23:59:00`). if you check the difference, you will get an idea

[image]

Is there any existing method or pandas function that can help us do this `datewise timedelta`? How can I shift the values datewise?

Comment: it's a little unclear what you want. can you show us the expected output?

Comment: Both the answers given below are really good. I can only mark one answer as solution, so I go with @anky_91 answer. Nonetheless SpghttCd answer was also good to know and solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
s=pd.to_timedelta(24,unit='h')-(df1.time_1-df1.time_1.dt.normalize())
df1['tdiff']=df1.groupby(df1.time_1.dt.date).time_1.diff().shift(-1).fillna(s)
#df1.groupby(df1.time_1.dt.date).time_1.diff().shift(-1).fillna(s).dt.total_seconds()/3600
```

---

```
    subject_id              time_1    tdiff
0            1 2173-04-03 12:35:00 00:15:00
1            1 2173-04-03 12:50:00 00:09:00
2            1 2173-04-03 12:59:00 00:15:00
3            1 2173-04-03 13:14:00 00:23:00
4            1 2173-04-03 13:37:00 10:23:00
5            1 2173-04-04 11:30:00 12:30:00
6            1 2173-04-05 16:00:00 06:00:00
7            1 2173-04-05 22:00:00 02:00:00
8            1 2173-04-06 04:00:00 00:30:00
9            1 2173-04-06 04:30:00 03:30:00
10           1 2173-04-06 08:00:00 16:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`df.dt.ceil`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html) to decide if to subtract from `time_2` or from midnight of `time_1`:

```
sameDayOrMidnight = df.time_2.where(df.time_1.dt.date==df.time_2.dt.date, df.time_1.dt.ceil(freq='1d'))
df['tdiff'] = (sameDayOrMidnight - df.time_1).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

result:

```
    subject_id              time_1              time_2      tdiff
0            1 2173-04-03 12:35:00 2173-04-03 12:50:00   0.250000
1            1 2173-04-03 12:50:00 2173-04-03 12:59:00   0.150000
2            1 2173-04-03 12:59:00 2173-04-03 13:14:00   0.250000
3            1 2173-04-03 13:14:00 2173-04-03 13:37:00   0.383333
4            1 2173-04-03 13:37:00 2173-04-04 11:30:00  10.383333
5            1 2173-04-04 11:30:00 2173-04-05 16:00:00  12.500000
6            1 2173-04-05 16:00:00 2173-04-05 22:00:00   6.000000
7            1 2173-04-05 22:00:00 2173-04-06 04:00:00   2.000000
8            1 2173-04-06 04:00:00 2173-04-06 04:30:00   0.500000
9            1 2173-04-06 04:30:00 2173-04-06 08:00:00   3.500000
10           1 2173-04-06 08:00:00                 NaT  16.000000
```